# How can I insert multiple records using a string ids for a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Title continued....
cause I want to avoid this error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Environment:  5.6.11 - MySQL, Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3

Trying to send a copy of a message to multiple recipients. This was previously working, and I just debugged it and for some reason the second execute is failing, but I am not getting any mention of an Exception, but I found an issue server side (detailed below)

Can multiple calls to a PDO execute statement be made by using a loop? If not why? I previously had this working and now all consecutive calls are failing.

Is there a better way to send an array of one or more recipients to a stored procedure so that an insert statement can be executed for each individual recipient?

If I send an string of 1,2. The response returned is:

Message sent to '1'

Message failed to be sent to '2'

Included below is the function insert_recipient and the stored procedure add_recipient

```
//connection to db, setting up of execption handling
$this->_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_host;dbname=$this->_dbname", $this->_dbusername, $this->_dbpassword);
$this->_dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

//method of inserting recipient, currently each recipient is added individually
//second call to this method currently fails to execute... why?
//is there a better method of sending a string of common separated values 
//and allow the stored procedure to insert all the records at once?

public function insert_recipient($recipientStr)
{
    try
    {
     // separate the csv
        $recipient_array = explode(",", $recipientStr);

        //bind a recipient and execute the statement / stored procedure
        foreach($recipient_array AS $recipient )
        {

            $statement =  $this->_dbh->prepare("Call add_recipient(?)");              
            $statement->bindParam(1, $recipient);                
            if($statement->execute()){
                echo "Message sent to '".$recipient."'.<br />";
            }else{
                echo "Message failed to be sent to '".$recipient."'. ";
                var_dump($statement);
            }

        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here is the stored procedure...

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_recipient`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `add_recipient`(
   IN recipientID BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO message_recipient(message_id, recipient_id, is_read ) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), recipientID, 0);
   SELECT thread_id FROM message WHERE message_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END//
```

I tried removing the SELECT statement and it still failed. I'm beginning to think the LAST_INSERT_ID() maybe the issue... since when I insert the first recipient into this table there is no auto_increment but somehow the insert of a new record is erasing the previous id. Does this sound correct? Cause documentation advices me that this function should be available based upon the last auto indexed field, which is how I am currently using it.

SERVER SIDE ISSUE:

I ran the following on the mysql console for phpmyadmin and I get the following error message:

```
call send_message("test123","test123",1);
call add_recipient(2);
call add_recipient(3);

SQL query:

call add_recipient( 3 ) ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Sorry - I know I have crammed a lot of info here. So take your time in responding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message was irrelevant to the issue. The error was the table structure and that the message id was set as the primary key when in fact the key should of been clustered with the recipient id.

It took 3-4 modifications of the stored procedures to be able to even recognize that it failing because it was inserting a duplicate on the sole primary key. The end result I have learned some new things.